# Create table schema error- Unsure why a schema error arises

Tags: mysql, sql, reference, create-table

This code throws a SCHEMA ERROR but it doesn't make sense as to why. Pls advise!

```
CREATE TABLE restaurantProfile (
  restaurantID CHAR(15),
  name VARCHAR(30),
  cuisineType VARCHAR(30),
  address VARCHAR(30),
  description VARCHAR(500),
  phone varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (restaurantID)
);

CREATE TABLE menu (
  menuID CHAR(15),
  dateStart date,
  restaurantID CHAR(15),
  PRIMARY KEY (menuID),
  FOREIGN KEY (restaurantID) REFERENCES restaurantProfile(restaurantID)
);

Error thrown: 
Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE menu ( menuID VARCHAR(15), dateStart date, restaurantID CHAR(' at line 10
```

Comment: Please look at the preview window before you post, you can use ``` or 4 char indentation to wrap your code in a code block, this will preserve the line wrapping and will colourise your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Please post the full error output that you receive from the SQL engine. Usually there will be line numbers and specific error codes that you can lookup that help explain this issue

Comment: The syntax is fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1d396a867910f716297de6c952ae423.

Comment: what kind of db you use ?

Comment: Turns out the error was with the db processor I was using, it was calling a non-error as an error. Used a different software and it worked fine. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE: this response is valid advice in MS SQL Databases, the question has been re-tagged as it is MySQL.

The Syntax is correct, the only issue here is the reference to the `restaurantProfile`

1. Check that the `restaurantProfile` table exists
   SImply selecting from the table should verify this, if your CREATE TABLE statement is part of a larger batch of statements, make sure that the principal table is created first.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM restaurantProfile
   ```
2. Confirm that the column `restaurantProfile.restaurantID` exists and the `TYPE` is `CHAR(15)`
   In Foreign key constraints, the source and target columns must have matching data types and in some RDBMS the principal end of the relationship needs to be defined as allowing Foreign key relationships.

   In MS SQL Sever we can run the following query to inspect the column information:

   ```
   SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
   WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'restaurantID'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'restaurantProfile'
   ```

   This should return something like this:

   ```
   TABLE_SCHEMA   TABLE_NAME          COLUMN_NAME    DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH   NUMERIC_PRECISION
   -------------- ------------------- -------------- ----------- -------------------------- -------------------
    dbo            restaurantProfile   restaurantID   char        15                         NULL
   ```